# Iterating through mutiple checkbox values and matching them against a single text input box's value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the value string of a text input field contains any matches that correspond with the values of multiple checkbox inputs. If a checkbox's value is found as a match within the text input's value string, that checkbox should be checked, while any unmatching checkbox should remain unchecked. With the code below, all of the checkboxes show up checked, while only one of the checkbox's value is a match for the text input's value string.

jQuery

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='hello']").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); 

    if ($("input[type='text'][name='goodbye']:contains("+value+")")) {
        $("input[id="+id+"]").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hello" id="1" value="1"><label for="1">one</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="hello" id="2" value="2"><label for="2">two</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="hello" id="3" value="3"><label for="3">three</label>

<input type="text" name="goodbye" id="goodbye" value="1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do a text compare the following should work

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='hello']").each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if ($('#goodbye').val().indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why you were going overly complicated to get the `goodbye` input, since you had an id and the id is always unique (or you'll have other issues).

```
$('#goodbye').val()
```

will give you the value in the input box. using `indexOf` will return -1 if the value is not found, a number 0 or greater if it is, so we can use that to figure out if the value exists.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/X74NK/1/

Comment: Thanks caspian, your code worked perfectly... looks like I was over-thinking it.